# Store Data From a form into a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie when it comes to javascript, I'm playing with different tutorials and trying to make my own simple things to get a better understanding of it all. Today's learning is all about passing parameters through a function. What I would like to do is have a user fill a form in, submit those answers to  variables in javascript and then call a function via an onClick event which will then display all the data entered into the form.

Firstly I hope this makes sense and secondly I hope that its the correct use of javascript, Im just trying to get a better understanding of passing params to be honest.

Could anyone advise any resources or point me in the right direction on where to get started with this small project

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

form elements are `select`, `input`, `textarea`.

On form, add a submit event handler which does the following

Using `document.getElementsByTagName` method, you can get a array of all such elements in the form.

All these elements have a `value` property which will return the current value in it. Using this, you can create a string will the current data when form is submitted.

Answer (score 5):

```
var data = document.getElementById('id').value;
```

check this:
 [js variables](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)

Answer (score 2):

In order to get values from textboxes/textarea/dropdown having unique ID, you can use

```
document.getElementBtId("IDOFTHECONTROL").value
```

If the input is DIV/SPAN, use innerHTML

```
   document.getElementBtId("IDOFTHECONTROL").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
var javascriptvar = document.getElementById('CONTROL_ID').value;
```